# How can I disregard a String if the String did not match entirely with the regex?

Tags: java, regex

For example, I want to disregard this String 123+456 78912, but the regex matched the first three characters, so it returned true. Is there a way to do that without creating a new regex?

The regex must also match the following:

+0 (123) 456-789-ABcd

+0 (123) 456

(123) 234 345-456

1111111111111

+1 123 123 123 123

123

123-(456)

123 (456) 789

+(phone)

(123)

```
private boolean checkValidity(String number){
    // Check value using regex and set value to field only if sastify these rules:
    //
    //   Phone number is split using space or dash
    //   Prefix may have +
    //   1st/2nd group have (), maximum only one grp
    //   grp contains number/upper/lowercase, at least two symbols in length
    //   1st grp may have one symbol in length

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\+?\\d{0,100}(\\w+[ -]+)*([ -]+\\(\\w+\\)[ -]+|[ -]+\\(\\w+\\)$|\\(\\w+\\)[ -]+|\\(\\w+\\)$){0,2}([ -]?\\w)*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(number);
    boolean matchFound = matcher.find();

    if(matchFound){
        return true;
    }
    System.out.println("Wrong number format!");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the original and matched values using matcher.group().equals

```
private boolean checkValidity(String number){
        //check value using regex and set value to field only if sastify these rules:
        //Phone number is split using space or dash
        //Prefix may have +
        //1st/2nd group have (), max only 1 grp
        //grp contains number/upper/lowercase, at least 2 symbols in length
        //1st grp may have 1 symbol in length

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^\\+?\\d{0,100}(\\w+[ -]+)*([ -]+\\(\\w+\\)[ -]+|[ -]+\\(\\w+\\)$|\\(\\w+\\)[ -]+|\\(\\w+\\)$){0,1}([ -]?\\w{2,100})*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(number);
        boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
        //System.out.println(matcher.group());
        if(matchFound && matcher.group().equals(number)){
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("Wrong number format!");
        return false;
    }
```